# Loop through alphbet for hotkey

Tags: vb.net, loops, foreach, to-char, registerhotkey

I am trying to find a way to set the hotkey using the following loop:

```
Dim hotKEY(1) as string
Dim tmpKey as new Keys
Dim chosenLetter As Char = "B"

hotKEY(0) = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
hotKEY(1) = "CTRL"

 For Each Letter In hotKEY(0).ToCharArray()
     If chosenLetter = Letter Then
        tmpKey = Asc(Letter)
        Exit For
     End If
Next

If hotKEY(1) = "SHIFT" Then 'shift
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_SHIFT, tmpKey)
ElseIf hotKEY(1) = "CTRL" Then 'control
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_CONTROL, tmpKey)
ElseIf hotKEY(1) = "ALT" Then 'alt
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_ALT, tmpKey)
ElseIf hotKEY(1) = "WIN" Then 'windows key
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_WIN, tmpKey)
End If
```

In the above code, **tmpKey** would be the chosen key letter (A-Z/0-9). However, I am unable to do this since it supposed to be **Keys.A, Keys.B, Keys.C, etc etc**.

Is this possible to do with my current code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i got it just now! :o)

```
Dim hotKEY(1) as string
Dim tmpKey as new Keys
Dim chosenLetter As Char = "B"

hotKEY(0) = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
hotKEY(1) = "CTRL"

 For Each Letter In hotKEY(0).ToCharArray()
     If chosenLetter = Letter Then
        tmpKey = Asc(Letter)
        Exit For
     End If
Next

If hotKEY(1) = "SHIFT" Then 'shift
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_SHIFT, tmpKey)
ElseIf hotKEY(1) = "CTRL" Then 'control
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_CONTROL, tmpKey)
ElseIf hotKEY(1) = "ALT" Then 'alt
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_ALT, tmpKey)
ElseIf hotKEY(1) = "WIN" Then 'windows key
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 100, MOD_WIN, tmpKey)
End If
```